# How to automating install software on 40+ virtual machine on ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi

Now I am managing a Free ESXi 5.1 Server and I often create new virtual machine in linked clone for developer to testing. The number of VMs is about 40. I have to log in to these VMs and install software for all of them.

You guys have any ideas to install software automatically by using script on esxi. Most of my VMs on Windows platform.

Comment: The free esxi is not really scriptable. I'd look for an outside solution.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds question isn't really specific to vSphere ESXi, but really is just "How can I automate software installation on a bunch of Windows machines (that just happen to be virtual)?"

The are a ton of ways to do this, from built-in functionality (chaining scripts onto the Windows installation process), the Windows Automated Installation Kit, Active Directory Group Policy, add-on Microsoft software (the System Center Configuration Manager product), and third-party commercial and free products.

Personally, I'd start looking at the built-in functionality in Windows and working toward offerings that have a monetary cost associated.